# Word find see question

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

I’m looking for a word that describes a UI element that serves no purpose but remains as an aesthetic holdover. Like a button on an iPhone screen that has shine to simulate an actual button, but it’s only an image of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is [skeuomorph](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skeuomorph).